# Get current time in BORLAND c

Tags: c, time, turbo-c

I saw somewhere that someone took the computer's current in a whole int,and started calculating hours minutes seconds,and i don't remember what function he used to get the time as an int, maybe `inportb` or `MK_FP` or something else,and i don't remember if it was in `dos.h`.Can someone help me,i tried to find this for some quite time.

Comment: You might have seen some ROM BIOS Interrupt location geting fetched using `MK_FP` with segment & offset address, de-referencing which returns number  of seconds elapsed. Please **don't use those**, `dos.h` is not supported by `gcc` and others too. They are obsolete and were used for MS-DOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard C, you can get the current time by calling the `time` function:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
```

which requires

```
#include <time.h>
```

The `NULL` argument is admittedly odd; it's there for historical reasons.

`time_t` is a numeric type capable of representing times. The way it does so is implementation-specific, but it's *typically* an integer representing the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. I'm not certain that Borland uses the same representation; consult your system's documentation for the `time` function.

`<time.h>` also provides various functions to convert between `time_t` values and `struct tm` (a "broken-down" time), to generate human-readable strings from times, and so forth.

There may be some other way to get the current time, something specific to Borland and/or MS-DOS. But unless you need better than 1-second resolution, or you're using an implementation that's so ancient it doesn't suport the `time` function properly, there's not much reason to use anything other than the standard `time` function.

Comment: don't forget to include time.h